# Dealing with Async in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asynchronous

I'm having trouble consuming an async service within MVC.  The service returns data which is used on all pages.  Hence my idea was to create a global action filter.  As is well documented you can not make async calls in an MVC action filter.

My question is, what approach do people use to get around this limitation?  I can't create a global action filter and I can't create a child action method for the same reason.

I'm currently considering creating a web API method and then using `WebClient` to make a synchronous call.  This feels like madness so would welcome any suggestions.

Comment: What is it exactly that you're trying to achieve? Action filters run before or after an action is executed... there shouldn't be anything that is making long running calls within them

Comment: @AydinAdn I need to get an Id, that is required on all pages.  The service method for this is async, so I wanted a way to add this globally without having to touch all the controllers and methods.

Comment: You've probably already thought of this, but, is there anything in the way of you storing it in cookies? The only other alternative I can think off is firing off an AJAX request on each page load, and have the script in your layout page, which could be a bad thing as much as a good thing depending on what the Id you're retrieving is responsible for..

Comment: Another idea is to create a controller that acts as a base class for your other controllers to derive from. The base class could override the `View` method and you could implement your logic there, only issue is that it would run after the logic within the controller action has been executed, though it should still be in the context of the separate thread.

Comment: @AydinAdn Yes, they are all solutions I have thought about.  At the moment I think I am going to go for the JavaScript approach.  I just would have preferred to keep it all together in the C# code.

Comment: I've recently [published a library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hydrogen.Extensions.Mvc5.Async) that adds proper support for async filters (heavily based on code in from [ASP.NET MVC Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc)).

Source is also available here: https://github.com/jdaigle/Hydrogen.Extensions.Mvc5.